# Hadoop issue, trying to run basic WordCount MapReduce on hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I'm running hadoop on my Windows 10 laptop, but I found some guides on getting it up and running and running a basic word count program. The hadoop installation seems fine as I'm able to see the dashboard when I go to http://localhost:8088/cluster/apps/NEW which I think means the "cluster" is up and running.

For reference, I'm doing this just to learn it for now which is why I'm using my laptop and Windows 10. The guide I'm following is here:

https://github.com/MuhammadBilalYar/Hadoop-On-Window/wiki/How-to-Run-Hadoop-wordcount-MapReduce-Example-on-Windows-10

Which worked well for a while, up until I had to actually submit a job, it goes to the ResourceManager, I can see it on the dashboard but then fails with a very non specific error here:

```
Application application_1525309913796_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1525309913796_0001_000002 exited with exitCode: 1
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1525309913796_0001_02_000001
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1:
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:972)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:869)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:1170)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:236)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:305)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:84)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Shell output: 1 file(s) moved.
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://BertieCoding:8088/cluster/app/application_1525309913796_0001 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
. Failing the application.
```

Before running the job, I ran these commands per the instructions:

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /input_dir
hadoop fs -put C:/input_file.txt /input_dir
hadoop fs -ls /input_dir/
hadoop jar C:/MapReduceClient.jar wordcount /input_dir /output_dir
```

Unfortunately when I look in the log directory of my hadoop installation, it has folders/files but the files don't have anything in them which doesn't seem right either.

Has anyone seen this before and knows how to fix it?

Oh I'm using HDFS as the underlying framework if that wasn't obvious. I can post the source code for the program as well but it seems like it's failing before it can even run it.

Comment: On that dashboard page, click on the FAILED link, then find the application logs from there

Comment: this is what I see when I click on the FAILED link and then on the the application ID: https://imgur.com/a/l3ucmnT

Comment: Okay, so I just found maybe more information, I'm getting this: '"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.". Which suggests the obvious that it isn't looking in the java directory, I can't find the config where this is set, though. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems your `PATH` environment variable and/or `JAVA_HOME` are not set up correctly. You might also want to upgrade your Java8 version, if you can

Comment: So I thought about that, so I changed my java installation so they're on C:\JAVA and if you check the album, again, I put a couple more screenshots in there of my environment variables. https://imgur.com/a/l3ucmnT?

Comment: `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` should be on the PATH, therefore the JAVA_HOME itself does not include the bin folder

Comment: Okay, I fixed that, thank you. I just tested it again and it's giving me the same error message.

Comment: Well, Java is clearly installed because Hadoop won't run without it. You'll need to restart all YARN processes after you are editing OS settings

Comment: I figured it out, thank you for your help, you made me re-examine my files so you helped out. I posted my answer.

Comment: Just for your reference: To just play with Hadoop you can use Hortonworks HDP sandbox virtual machine template and run in on top of VirtualBox application. This is already preconfigured with all necessary applications like Yarn, Hive, Spark, etc. In this case you don't need to spend time on configuration by your own.

Comment: Oh, that would have been easier. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0):

In the hadoop-env.cmd file, where you set the JAVA_HOME path, do NOT use quotation marks around the path.

For instance, I had set it as:

```
set JAVA_HOME="C:\java"
```

but instead do this:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\java
```

Very simple fix, causing so many problems.

Comment: I'm pretty sure quotes are needed if spaces are in that path. Also, this shouldn't really matter, IMO

Comment: Well originally I had the path be "C:\Program Files\Java\blahblah" for that reason but then it would say "C:\Program" is not a command. I think in that case you'd want to use C:\Progra~1\Java\blahblah to remove the quotes. In the environment vars, I use that notation but didn't think about in the hadoop command environment.